# Can a 51% attack be triggered by any other of these 7 strategies? (and with a quantum computer?)

Tags: attack, majority-attack

(I think this question will be blocked for being not specific, so help me edit it, thanks)

(I will present **Facts [1]** and **Facts [2]** which will help organize my ideas before my question)

**Facts [1]**: (the following information is common sense)

One possible attack is: (reproducing the words in the blog [braiins](https://braiins.com/blog/can-quantum-computers-51-attack-bitcoin))

> ...public keys are **revealed** when transactions are broadcasted to the
> mempool, even **BEFORE** they get added to the blockchain.
>
> If an attacker could **reverse the signature** and get the associated
> private key during this window before the transaction gets included
> on-chain, they could then broadcast a higher-fee transaction sending
> the coins to themselves instead.

**Facts [2]**: (the difficult part of the question will start here)

The paper [A Survey on Various Attacks in Bitcoin and Cryptocurrency](https://ieeexplore.ieee.org/abstract/document/8697996) describes 7 attacks:

```
A. Denial-of-service Attack 
B. Double Spending Attack 
C. Sybil Attack 
D. Eclipse Attack 
E. Selfish mining Attack 
F. Fork after Withholding Attack 
G. Block Withholding Attack
```

I finally arrive to my question:

*Using a quantum computer to break SHA-256/ECDSA:*

**Are there other tricks to pull off a 51% attack throughout any of the (A-G) strategies?**

(I have tried to find any not widespreadly diffuse knowledge, like

For example 1: In Eclipse attack, the IP address of victim person is blocked or redirected towards a competitor. [IPsec](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/IPsec) uses SHA. So I think it is possible to find a vulnerability this way, but I have no idea how.

For example 2: It is written in the paper [Off-Path TCP Exploits of the Mixed IPID Assignment](https://arxiv.org/pdf/2008.12981.pdf):

*"TCP connections DoS attack is particularly applicable to compromising applications secured by encrypted traffic, e.g., HTTPS and SSH"*.

I have tried to guess which quantum attack to sha256 is able to attack bitcoin, but I am not a computer scientist so please ANY information is wellcome)